# The best way to check if a volume is mounted in a shell script in Mac OS?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, mount

I had a shell script which I automated a copying process from my phone's folder to a local folder on my Mac and then deleted the originals on the phone. Previously I wrote

```
cd /Users/foo/Phone\ Backups/Phone\ One/Pictures
echo "Meta info of the picture files in the local folder before backup"  >> /Users/foo/Documents/preBackup.txt
find .  -exec stat -c " %n size %s bytes; LMT %y; CT %w; LAT %x; LSC %z; %F; Owned by: %U" {} \; | tee -a /Users/foo/Documents/preBackup.txt


cp -a /Volumes/Foo\'s\ Phone\ One\ Pictures/. /Users/foo/Phone\ Backups/Phone\ One/Pictures
echo "Backup complete. Delete all records on the phone."
cd /Volumes/Foo\'s\ Phone\ One\ Pictures
find . ! -type d -delete
echo "Deleted."
```

Today when I ran my script I accidentally forgot to plug in my phone, and also afterward to my surprise all the picture files in my local folder got deleted as well. I guess it is because it didn't find my phone's picture folder so it was still in my local folder when it ran the command "find . ! -type d -delete".

So now just wanna ask what's the best way to check if a volume is mounted in a shell script in Mac OS and if the name of the volume has ' and space?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Best place to start in the "df" command.

Comment: Why is it important to know if the name of the volume has `'` and space? I don't see anything in your code snippet where that would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a volume is mounted,
you can simply use the `[ -d ... ]` command to check if the directory exists, for example:

```
[ -d "/Users/foo/Phone Backups/Phone One/Pictures" ] || exit 1
```

But that's not the biggest concern here.
Not checking the exit code of commands is the real problem,
and it can easily lead to data loss as in your example.

You should always check the exit code of commands,
especially when something dangerous follows such as deleting the source files.
In this example, the `cp` command fails when the volume is not mounted,
you could have checked it and handled it.

For example:

```
fatal() {
    echo fatal: "$@"
    exit 1
}

cd "/Users/foo/Phone Backups/Phone One/Pictures" || fatal 'Could not cd into backups dir'
```

This can get a bit tedious, as you have many commands that can fail.
All the `cd`, `cp`, `find`, `rm` can fail.

Another alternative is to set some flags in the shell so that it automatically exits when a program fails, or other suspicious thing happens, such as referencing an undefined variable.
Simply add this at the top of your script, and it will be safer to run, even in case of failures in the middle:

```
set -euo pipefail
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common and risky problem, not only for mounting volumes.

When you start doing destructive stuff its always wise to double check if your in the correct folder. A `rm -fr` could otherwise ruin your day.

Simple example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple check to see wether we are in the correct folder
if [ $(pwd) == '/home/foo/files' ]; then
    echo "I'm in the correct folder"
    # do what you need to do...
else
    echo "This folder [$(pwd)] is NOT the correct folder! Abort..."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
limit="some limit"
df /User 2> /dev/null | awk -v limit=$limit '$1 != "Filesystem" { if ($4 < limit) { print "There is not enough space";exit 1 } }'
if [[ $0 != "1" ]]
then
       do stuff here.....
fi
```

Here we set a limit to check the file system space against and then we run the df command on /User piping through awk utilising the limit set. If there is no mounted file system the return status of the command will be one. If there is not enough space, awk will also return a 1. Only when the return status is not 1 can we continue.